# Find $T(a+bx+cx^2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let the linear transformation $T: \mathbb P_2 \rightarrow M_{2\times2}$

Find $T(a+bx+cx^2)$

knowing that:

$$T(1+x)=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

$$T(x+x^2)=\begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$$

$$T(1+x^2)=\begin{bmatrix} 0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

I believe that it can be solved by combinations of the known transformations. But I've been stuck with this problem for a while.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

To start with, solve the following system in terms of $a,b$ and $c$.

\begin{align*}
a+bx+cx^{2} = p(1+x) + q(x+x^{2}) + r(1+x^{2}) \Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
a = p + r\\
b = p + q\\
c = q + r
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Once you know $p,q$ and $r$, you get
\begin{align*}
T(a + bx + cx^{2}) = pT(1+x) + qT(x+x^{2}) + rT(1+x^{2})
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:  $a+bx+cx^2=\dfrac{a+b-c}2(1+x)+\dfrac{c+b-a}2(x+x^2)+\dfrac{c+a-b}2(1+x^2)$

Answer (score 0):

First, realise that $\{1+x,1+x^2,x(1+x)\}$ is a linearly independent family; this lets you find out a basis for $\mathbb {P}_2$, as you know $\mathbb {P}_2$ has 3 dimensions.
Consider a basis for $M_{2\times2}$ and do the transformation Matrix (of size 4x3).